# How to prevent FormatException and IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception, indexoutofrangeexception

This code throws a Format Exception when a wrong input is input by the user at the conversion of the string to int. It also doesn't reach the desired output of "All first class seats have been booked" when 32 tickets have been sold, it just throws an index out of range exception. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
class FirstClassCompartment
{ 
    public void FirstClassTickets()
    {
        bool[] seats = new bool[32];
        List<int> seatsBooked = new List<int>();
        int completeBooking = 0;
        bool quit = false;
        string ticketAmount = "";
        int firstClassSeat = 0;
        int convertedTicketAmount;
        {
            Groups firstClass = new Groups();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the First Class booking menu");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of tickets you would like to book");
            ticketAmount = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nFirst Class booking menu");
                    convertedTicketAmount = Convert.ToInt32(ticketAmount);
                    ticketAmount = firstClass.NumberInGroupFirstClassWest;
        }

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nFirst Class booking menu");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please press 1 to complete your first class booking");
            completeBooking = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (completeBooking)
            {
                case 1:

                    if (seatsBooked.Count == 0)
                    {
                        firstClassSeat++;
                        seats[firstClassSeat] = true;
                        seatsBooked.Add(firstClassSeat);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        do
                        {
                            firstClassSeat++;
                            if (!seatsBooked.Contains(firstClassSeat))
                            {
                                seats[firstClassSeat] = true;

                            }
                        }
                        while (seatsBooked.Contains(firstClassSeat) && seatsBooked.Count < 32);
                        if (seatsBooked.Count < 32)
                        {
                            seatsBooked.Add(firstClassSeat);
                        }
                    }
                    if (seatsBooked.Count > 32)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("All seats for first class have been booked");
                        Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to continue...");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your seat: {0}", firstClassSeat + 1);
                        Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to continue...");

                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a valid input");
                    quit = true;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!quit);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `Int.TryParse()` and display an error to the user if that returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) and check the returned `bool`.

<s>Look at the logic in you switch statement, you only handle a booking of 1.  What if the user books 2 seats?</s>
*Edit: Sorry, just realised that switch statement is to handle the menu, not number of bookings*

Do you need a list of `int`s, as well as an array of `bool`s in order to track how many seats have been booked?  Couldn't you just use a plain old `int`, e.g. `numberOfSeatsBooked`?  Then you can do `numberOfSeatsBooked += convertedTicketAmount;`

Comment: I haven't quite got that far yet, I just wanted to get rid of these exceptions first. Also, the List seems to start from 2 (the first ticket sold is 2) is there any reason for this to happen as far as you can see?

Comment: Getting rid of arrays and lists will get rid of `IndexOutOfRangeException`, and using `TryParse` will get rid of `NumberFormatException`.
Remember that a list is literally that, imagine writing it on a piece of paper.  Now are you talking about the *size* of the list, or the *first element*.  If you sell 2 tickets, what your code `seatsBooked.Add(firstClassSeat);` does is add 2 to the list.  The list *size* will be 1, and the only *element* in the list will be the number 2.

Comment: I understand the logic of that but I'm unsure of the syntax I would need to use to keep track of the booked seats using an array of bools?

Comment: You only need the array of `bool`s if you are interested in tracking *individual* seats (which you're not currently doing).  If you only need to track *quantity* of seats, a plain `int` is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this very differently. You should have a class for seats containing a boolean for booked and iterate that rather than a random array of books that may or may not be linked to a random list of booked seats and a number of seats booked. Here's a small example:

```
public class Seat
{
    public int SeatNo { get; set; }
    public bool FirstClass { get; set ; }
    public bool Booked { get; set; } // could actually be an instance of a booking info class including name and ticket id, etc.
}

public class Flight
{
    public List<Seat> Seats = new List<Seat>();
    private int _lastSeat = 0;
    public void AddSeats(int num, bool firstClass)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            _lastSeat++;
            Seats.Add(new Seat { SeatNo = num, FirstClass = firstClass });
        }
    }

    public int BookNextAvailableSeat(bool firstClass)
    {
        foreach (Seat seat in Seats.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.FirstClass == firstClass)
        {
            if (!seat.Booked)
            {
                seat.Booked = true;
                return seat.SeatNo;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then your:

```
case 1:
    int booking = flight.BookNextAvailableSeat(true);
    if (booking != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Your seat: {0}", booking);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("All seats for first class have been booked");
    Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to continue...");
    break;
```

Of course you need to instantiate flight and add the 32 seats using:

```
Flight flight = new Flight();
flight.AddSeats(32, true);
```